# Umbraco - SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, umbraco

I'm looking to add an SSL certificate to my umbraco cms site, does anyone have any useful links or ideas how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The SSL cert needs to be added to the IIS webserver that is hosting your umbraco site.

Your SSL or hosting provider should have instructions on installing the cert.

Additional:

Once the cert is installed you can force HTTPS in the Umbraco section by changing the appSetting `umbracoUseSSL` in the web.config to true

```xml
<appSettings>
  <add key="umbracoUseSSL" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

In the website you can use the [HTTPS redirect package](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/https-redirect) to redirect the required pages to use SSL

Comment: It works for hosting Umbraco website in IIS. But it doesn't work when developing using visual studio, any idea?

Comment: if I recall correctly, VS spins up an IIS instance, so you'd need one install there, not sure why you want a local cert though. It's been a couple years since I did anything related to this though.

Comment: I set umbracoUseSSL to true and run debugging through VS2013 Express using IIS Express http://localhost:49652/. When I try to go to Umbraco back offcie url http://localhost:49652/umbraco/, it redirects me to https://localhost/umbraco/Login.aspx. It is a empty page and I can not login to Umbraco back office page.